# Store different sized matrices and values to a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

I'm generating a bunch of data for a project using a series of loops and want to save the values so I don't have to keep generating them each time. My problem is the data varies a lot in size and location (see below), which is making it difficult to store properly. I was hoping to just dump it into a dataframe with the various matrices occupying a single cell.

Code for Generating data

```
for (simulation in 1:1000){
       g <- ceiling(runif(1, min=0, max=3))
       if (g==1) {sample1 = runif(1, min=100, max=3000)}
       if (g==2) {sample1 = runif(1, min=100, max=1500)
                  sample2 = runif(1, min=100, max=1500)}
       if (g==2) {sample1 = runif(1, min=100, max=1000)
                  sample2 = runif(1, min=100, max=1000)
                  sample3 = runif(1, min=100, max=1000)}
       samplesize=sample1+sample2+sample3
       for (class in 1:g){
            x1 = c()
            ... 
            x30 = c()
            for (i in 1:samplesize){
                   x1[i]=rnorm(1,1.5,1)
                   ...
                   x30[i]=rnorm(1,1.5,1)
                   
            }
      data = matrix(c(x1:x30))
      conditions[simulation,1] = g
      conditions[simulation,2] = sample1
      conditions[simulation,3] = sample2
      conditions[simulation,4] = sample3

      }
}
```

This generates 30 variables (x1-x30) a samplesize amount of times which varies depending on how many groups (1-3). So if there is one group, there could be anywhere between (30 * 100) to (30 * 3000) variables. For three groups, there could be (30 * 3 * 100) to (30 * 3 * 1000), and they can be different for each of the groups. Hence, the data is somewhat regular, but, shifts around.

What I want to do is take the matrix of simulated values (x1:x30) and store that in a dataframe along with the simulation conditions for each simulation. This would be something like the first cell in the dataframe being a nested matrix of x values, while the other cells in that row would be singular values (the conditions). I've seen a few posts about doing this using a double bracket [[]], but can't figure how to implement this in my data. Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: You could use a `list` instead of a `data.frame`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about using a list-column as the last column of your data.frame.
I did this using `data.table`.

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
set.seed(42)
the_list <- vector('list')
for (simulation in 1:1000){
  sample1 = 1
  sample2 = 0
  sample3 = 0
  g <- ceiling(runif(1, min=0, max=3))
  if (g==1) {sample1 = runif(1, min=100, max=3000)}
  if (g==2) {sample1 = runif(1, min=100, max=1500)
  sample2 = runif(1, min=100, max=1500)}
  if (g==2) {sample1 = runif(1, min=100, max=1000)
  sample2 = runif(1, min=100, max=1000)
  sample3 = runif(1, min=100, max=1000)}
  samplesize=sample1+sample2+sample3
  for (class in 1:g){
    x1 = c()
    x30 = c()
    for (i in 1:samplesize){
      x1[i]=rnorm(1,1.5,1)
      x30[i]=rnorm(1,1.5,1)
      
    }
    data = cbind(x1, x30)

  }
  the_list[[simulation]] <- list(simulation, g, sample1, sample2, sample3, list(data))
}
conditions <- rbindlist(the_list) %>% 
  setnames(c('sim', 'g', 'sample1', 'sample2', 'sample3', 'result'))
```

The second simulation is conditions[2] or conditions[sim == 2]
For the first 10 rows of results from simulation 2, you would use:

```
conditions[2]$result[[1]][1:10, ]
             x1       x30
 [1,] 3.054896 0.3123586
 [2,] 1.651813 0.4138674
 [3,] 3.113373 1.5356312
 [4,] 2.814959 2.4781675
 [5,] 2.381791 1.9822047
 [6,] 2.465753 0.6854291
 [7,] 1.783958 1.3383014
 [8,] 3.435572 3.2232308
 [9,] 1.858402 1.8024309
[10,] 1.105885 2.2881406
```